# AspTokenInput Enable And Disable

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-plugins

I used `AspTokenInput` Which is used as `AutoComplete TextBox` to create Tags .

I use **[this](https://github.com/harindaka/ASPTokenInput/wiki)** Link To know How to Use it.

It's Works Fine For Me and give Result As I want.

Now I want to Make This Control Enabled or Disabled On a Button Click according To Condition.

I Use this on Button Click

```
AspTokenInput.Enabled = "False"
```

But it's not Working...

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the jQuery Tokeninput field cannot be disabled serverside.

See (http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/) for documentation on this library if you want to try and finagle the js on and off. At a glance, I don't see an enable/disable flag or method. You may need to dig into the ASPTokenInput library to see how it pulls its data source, and then enable/disable the plugin with:

```
$("#my-text-input").tokenInput("clear"); //disable
$("#my-text-input").tokenInput("/url/to/ASPTokenInput/Datasource/");//reenable
```

The problem with this approach is that it basically goes around the ASPTokenInput layer, which kind of defeats the point.

My secondary approach was to try a hack, but hiding the dropdown isn't the greatest solution (or even easy in this case), nor is having the check box swap the autocomplete input for another. Swapping text boxes is probably the simplest solution.